# Get string with one ID and two &?

Tags: php, get

Im running a website for a client which is accessed when a get string is passed to it, I just received their new link, and there are 5 things I need to pull from the link. one of the items is an ID, so the get string would look like this normally:

```
www.website.com/index.php?id=1232352346
```

which is how it was being sent before, however this newest one has it set up like this:

```
www.website.com/index.php?id=2345134&123461
```

what Im wondering is if I pull that id in like so

```
$id=htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"], ENT_QUOTES);
```

will it have just the number before the second & (ex: 2345134) or will it have the entire thing (ex: 2345134&123461)?

Comment: `Array ( [id] => 2345134 [123461] => ) ` 1234561 is just a blank value.

Comment: @jasper The reason Im posting this is because I cannot try it until they finalize the url which they cannot do until I get back to them. bonzo thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Baba: Observing the contents of `$_GET` will most certainly "work" when you define "work" as "finding out the answer to this question"

Comment: @Kynian: Yes you can. You can try it with the URL you gave us.

Comment: @What exactly do you want  ??? the entire thing ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're not URL encoding the `&`, then the second half of the ID is going to be treated as another parameter - regardless of how you might process `$_GET`

There are a few ways you could try to parse it - one simplistic method would be to check for an empty parameter and assume that's the other half of the id. You could also ignore how the query string is parsed, and parse it yourself (perhaps ignoring any `&` found inside two digits).

But really, the best thing to do is **make sure the url is properly encoded** - then everything will work as expected.

Here's how the URL you provided will be parsed (using [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), which should match how `$_GET` is populated):

```
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(7) "2345134"
  [123461]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Here's how this correctly formatted URL will be parsed:

`/index.php?id=1234%265678`

```
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(9) "1234&5678"
}
```

If the client is generating the URLs using PHP, then they can use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) and all the encoding is handled automatically.

Answer (score 2):

**If you want them apart you can try this quick fix**

```
array_walk($_GET, function(&$i,$k){empty($i) AND $i=$k;});
var_dump($_GET);
```

Output

```
array
  'id' => string '2345134' (length=7)
  123461 => int 123461
```

If you **want the entire string** and `id` is the only key in the URL you can try

```
list($key, $value) = explode("=", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
var_dump($key,$value);
```

Output

```
string 'id' (length=2)
string '2345134&123461' (length=14)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "www.website.com/index.php?id=2345134&123461";
$parsed = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parsed["query"], $query);
var_dump($query);
```

Keep in mind that `parse_url` fails for invalid URLs.

---

This should work:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
unset($_GET["id");
$keys = array_keys($_GET);
unset($keys);
$other = $_GET[$keys[0]];
var_dump($id, $other);
```

Comment: Oh, I see, your URLs are malformed. Tell your client to get their shit together and make proper URLs.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$url = "2345134&123461";
$pieces = explode("&", $url);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
 var_dump($pieces );
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/H5tZ2Agn)

Answer (score 0):

How about.. 
www.website.com/index.php?id=2345134&123461

```
//explode it
        $string=$_GET['id'];
        list($first,$second)=explode('&',$string);
//$first = 2345134
//$second = 123461
```

Holy bejesus answers come fast..

Comment: In all cases (using the provided query string of `id=2345134&123461`), `$_GET['id']` will not contain the second half.